# Offer options if record already exists in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm creating a database of products and want to check when a new product is created, if that product already exists.

99% of the time, the product should have a unique product code, but sometimes this will not be the case when a revised version comes out with the same product code.

I would like to have it so that the database checks if the product code exists already. If it does, then the user can either go ahead and create the product anyway, go to the product that already exists, or cancel.

I am trying to achieve this in the controller but cannot seem to get the syntax of the exists? method correct. Can someone point out where I am going wrong, please?

```
def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)

    if Product.product_code.exists?(@product.product_code)
        render 'new'
        flash[:error] = "This product already exists."

    elsif @product.save
        redirect_to @product
    else
        render 'new'
    end

end
```

Comment: You can use active record's validations (uniqueness validation) on the product_code field so `@product` won't save if the product_code is already in use and then you can check if `@product.errors[:product_code]` show the taken error.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Instead `if Product.product_code.exists?(@product.product_code)` possibly you should use `if @product.product_code.present?`

UPD: thanks to all, commented below.

Correct use of `exists?` is `Product.where(product_code: @product.product_code).exists?`

Comment: I tried that - unfortunately it gives an error: undefined method `exists?' for "1234":String

Comment: undefined method `exists?' for "1234":String    - 1234 is the product code I was trying out.

Comment: That's got it! Thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't think [`exists?`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-exists-3F) is deprecated. APIDock is quite out of date but they do note that [`exists?`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods/exists%3F) was moved to `FinderMethods`.

Comment: Correct use of `exists?` is `Product.where(product_code: @product.product_code).exists?`

Answer (score 0):

You should note that what you are doing in the controller or adding a standard uniqueness validation to the model will not allow duplicate Products to be created at all.

This will just keep sending the user back to the form:

```
def create
  @product = Product.new(product_params)
  if Product.exists?(product_code: @product.product_code)
    render 'new'
    flash[:error] = "This product already exists."
  elsif @product.save
    redirect_to @product
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

If you want to simply warn the user once you can attach a [virtual attribute](https://metova.com/rails-5-attributes-api/) on the model and use it as condition for the validation:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  attribute :dup_warning, :boolean, default: true
  validate :lax_product_code_uniquenes

  def lax_product_code_uniqueness
    if new_record? && !dup_warning && Product.exists(product_code: self.product_code)
      errors.add(:product_code, 'is not unique - are you sure?')
      self.dup_warning = true
    end
  end
end
```

Then add the virtual attribute to the form:

```
<%= form_with(model: @product) do |f| %>
  ...
  <%= f.hidden_input(:dup_warning) %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

And you don't need to really do anything in the controller besides add `dup_warning` to the params whitelist.

```
def create
  @product = Product.new(product_params)
  if @product.save
    redirect_to @product
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

def product_params
  params.require(:product)
        .permit(:foo, :bar, :product_code, :dup_warning)
end
```